# Excel vba relative cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I feel this may be an easy question that I just can't seem to find an answer for.
When using vba in Excel to write subs/macro's, how do I use a relative reference.

To clarify, I currently have a macro that checks the value of a number of cells then hides or shows specific rows based on the values. For example:

```
If variable1.value = "Yes" then
    Rows("53").Hidden = True
Else
    Rows("53").Hidden = False
End If
```

Now if I insert a new row above row 53, the macro still hides row 53, but the content that needs to be hidden has actually moved to row 54. I'd prefer it to be dynamic so that I don't need to manually change the row numbers each time the document is amended; either with rows added or rows removed.

Comment: So there is nothing in the row that can located to identify it?

Comment: The document is a checklist. Each row is just a string of text with a dropdown box to select Yes/No. Based on earlier questions though, some questions are not applicable and so the row is set to hide itself.
I think I can look into naming the rows but if I can avoid that, I'd like to.

Comment: You can use named range, give `A53` a name like `myRow` then use `Range("myRow").EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested that and it works. I was hoping to avoid having to name several ranges throughout the workbook but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was written in the comments by Fadi.
I need to define names for the rows that are affected, e.g. name Row 53 `myRow` and then use

```
Range("myRow").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```